# How to create COMPUTED column in MS SQL by ENTITY FRAMEWORK CORE code first with condition (string + auto increment number)

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to create a computed column in MS SQL with the help of [HasComputedColumnSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/computed-columns), But unable to understand How.

My condition for column is **"ABCD-Auto incremental value minimum 8 character"**.

I want the column with value **ABCD-00000001**

I have done it in SQL query and it is working.

`CREATE TABLE BikeParts (
    BikeParts_GUID AS 'ABCD-' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
    BikePart_ID), 8),
    BikePart_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    BikePart_Name VARCHAR(100)
)`

INSERT INTO BikeParts VALUES ('Break Cable')
INSERT INTO BikeParts VALUES ('Seat Cover')

SELECT * FROM BikeParts

But unable to do same in entity framework core 2.2 with code first approach.

I will be really thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: *unable to do same* -- Please elaborate. What did you try to achieve and what were you unable to do?

Comment: @GertArnold As i mentioned above, I need a column which generate value automatically in given format (ABCD-00000001). This is possible in MS SQL but don't know how to do it by entity-framework core code first.

Comment: I assume you tried to use the method `HasComputedColumnSql` but you don't show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of search, finally I got the correct answer.

**Model is:-**

```
public partial class BikeParts
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string BikePartsGuid { get; set; }
        public int BikePartId { get; set; }
        public string BikePartName { get; set; }
    }
```

**And configuration of model is:-**

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {

        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("BikePartIdHelper", schema: "dbo").StartsAt(1).IncrementsBy(1);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BikeParts>(entity =>
        {
                entity.ToTable("BikeParts1");
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);
                entity.Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ID").UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
                entity.Property(e => e.BikePartId).HasColumnName("BikePart_ID")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.BikePartIdHelper");
                entity.Property(e => e.BikePartName)
                    .HasColumnName("BikePart_Name")
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
                entity.Property(e => e.BikePartsGuid)
                    .HasColumnName("BikeParts_GUID")
                    .HasMaxLength(13)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasComputedColumnSql("('ABCD-'+right(replicate('0',(8))+CONVERT([varchar],[BikePart_ID]),(8)))");
        });        
 }
```

I used [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences) for auto-generate BikePartId with the help of [HasDefaultValueSql](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasdefaultvaluesql-method)
and on BikePartsGuid column I used [HasComputedColumnSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/computed-columns)